# How to binding command in reusable ViewCell in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

In my project, I have two `ListView` in different `ViewModels` whit same `ViewCell` content. I extract this `ViewCell` in other `XAML` file to reuse in `ListView` like this:

```
    <views:MvxContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView x:Name="scrollList">
        <StackLayout x:Name="Root">
                    <!-- ... -->

            <repeater:RepeaterView x:Name="MainList" ShowSeparator="False"
                                   SelectedItemCommand="{Binding SelectedCommand}"
                                   IsVisible="True"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <repeater:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:ItemList FavoriteCommand="Binding path=FavCommand, Source={x:Reference MainList}}"
                                                        FavoriteCommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </repeater:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>

            </repeater:RepeaterView>

                     <!-- ... -->

        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</views:MvxContentPage.Content>
...
```

This works perfectly to show data but when binding command in the label, it's not working.

```
<views:MvxViewCell
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
x:TypeArguments="viewModels:ItemListViewModel"
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Template.Core.ViewModels;assembly=Template.Core"

                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  x:Class="Template.Core.Views.ItemList"
                  xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
                  xmlns:iconize="clr-namespace:Plugin.Iconize;assembly=Plugin.Iconize"
                  xmlns:Helpers="clr-namespace:Template.Core.Helpers">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Source="ukflag"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.RowSpan="4"
               WidthRequest="50"
               HeightRequest="80"
               Grid.Column="0" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Nombre}"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="1"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               FontSize="15" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Direcciones[0].toString}"
               Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.Column="1"
               FontSize="11" />
        <iconize:IconLabel Text="fas-heart"
                           BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           Grid.Column="2"
                           FontSize="35"
                           Grid.RowSpan="2"
                           VerticalOptions="Center">
            <iconize:IconLabel.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding FavCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
            </iconize:IconLabel.GestureRecognizers>
        </iconize:IconLabel>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                     Grid.Row="3"
                     Grid.Column="1">
            <iconize:IconLabel Text="fas-map-marker-alt"
                               TextColor="Black"
                               FontSize="15" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Distancia}"
                   FontSize="13" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</views:MvxViewCell>



public partial class ItemList

{

    public ItemList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

Before to separate ViewCell in the file, binding works correctly but now not call ViewModel command. My idea is binding two commands from the view where it is. How can it be done? Many thanks!!

Comment: Can you share the whole ViewCell's source code including code behind (I guess it is the `ItemList` element)? Looks like the `BindingContext` is not being set properly

Comment: Hello! I just edited the code to show everything. Thank you very much!

Comment: Humn... You're using MvvmCross, I don't know how it works or if it is interfering on the behavior, but check out my answer, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how is your proficiency in Xamarin Forms, but definitely it isn't a beginner's code. I think it was just a misunderstanding. The issue you've described looks like a binding issue, as I've commented.

So, the cake recipe is:

1. Expose in the custom view cell those properties you want to be able to use externaly;
2. Bind the internal view cell properties into the elements as you want;
3. Use the custom view cell with external binds.

The step by step walkthrough:

## 1 - Exposing properties enabling external bindings

I believe you I'll get the expected result just adding the properties you want to be bound outside like bindable properties:

```
// viewCell's code-behind
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class ItemListCell : ContentView
{
    public static BindableProperty NameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Name), typeof(string), typeof(ItemListCell));
    public string Name
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(NameProperty);
        set => SetValue(NameProperty, value);
    }

    public static BindableProperty FavoriteCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FavoriteCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(ItemListCell));
    public ICommand FavoriteCommand
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(FavoriteCommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(FavoriteCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static BindableProperty FavoriteCommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FavoriteCommandParameter), typeof(object), typeof(ItemListCell));
    public object FavoriteCommandParameter
    {
        get => GetValue(FavoriteCommandParameterProperty);
        set => SetValue(FavoriteCommandParameterProperty, value);
    }

    public static BindableProperty DistanceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Distance), typeof(string), typeof(ItemListCell));
    public string Distance
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(DistanceProperty);
        set => SetValue(DistanceProperty, value);
    }

    public ItemListCell ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }
}
```

## 2 - Using properties on [view-cell's] internal bindings

On your ViewCell xaml you should bind the internal elements properties to a known binding context (in this case I made it be called `This`). See the examples on `Label` and `TapGestureRecognizer`:

```
// viewCell's XAML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App2.ItemListCell"
             x:Name="This">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid BindingContext="{x:Reference This}">
            <!-- Keep all the viewcell xaml source code unmodified -->
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <!-- ... -->
            <iconize:IconLabel.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding FavoriteCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding FavoriteCommandParameter}" />
            </iconize:IconLabel.GestureRecognizers>
            <!-- ... -->
            <!-- Keep all the viewcell xaml source code unmodified -->
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**Notice the Grid's `BindingContext` set and the view cell's binding to internal properties which are exposed to external bindings**

## 3 - Using the custom view cell

Here you will use your custom view cell and bind with the item list object. Then it should works fine. It should be like this:

```
...
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:ItemListCell Name="{Binding Nombre}"
                                FavoriteCommand="{Binding FavCommand}"
                                FavoriteCommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
...
```

## Updating: In case you are using a single implementation of FavCommand on your page's view model:

```
<ContentPage ...
             x:Name="PageInstance">
    ...
    <ListView ...>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:ItemListCell Name="{Binding Nombre}"
                                    FavoriteCommand="{Binding BindingContext.FavCommand, Source={x:Reference PageInstance}}"
                                    FavoriteCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                    .../>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hello
I have problems with the Listview. I've changed it for RepaterView. I can not bind my FavCommand. I have debugged and never call the set method, only the get. I have followed the instructions of your code, including I have tested with Listview and it still does not work. What can happen? Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know about RepeaterView. The `FavCommand` you're binding is a command implemented on `ItemViewModel` or `PageViewModel`? I guess it is the second one. In this case, you have to make a cross binding just to the command bind on client. See my update.

Comment: @pablogupi what kind of problem with `ListView`?